# Can you please identifiy the direction of light in this photo?

Tags: illustration, shadows, lighting-effects

So we have this image and we have added a flamingo over it. The problem is we can't identify the direction of light currectly and it makes the shadow we made for the flamingo so bad. Can you please tell us in which direction should our lighting be?

[image]

Update: This is the image without any manipulation:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Looks like it has been manipulated, probably several photos/elements, so it would just be a guess. The mountains in the distance have shadows to the left, and highlights to the right.

Comment: Can you show the landscape photo before any manipulation was done?

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks a lot for your kind welcome! And thanks a lot for the direction.

Comment: @BillyKerr  - Thanks a lot for your messages. I added the original photo that I found in the unsplash. I don't have any more than this.

Comment: @user287001 thanks a lot for your message. Yeah the flamingo is by us. I added the main photo to the question.

Comment: Have to be honest, but the teepee looks like it has been cut and pasted, and not in a realistic way.  There aren't many other clues in the rest of the image other than the mountains. maybe the boulders in the foreground. Shadows to the bottom left, upper right is in highlight.

Answer (score 3):

I think the light come from behind the camera, on the right and a little low, but there is probably a mountain casting a soft shadow over all the foreground. (the shadow stop on the hill behind the teepee, you can see the light).

Zoom on the original in the foreground to see if right :

[image: Shadow hint foreground]

[image: Shadow hint moutain]

[image: Shadow hint hill]

PS : Don't think it's a photo manipulation, i think the teepee is on the landscape, you can zoom in the real size photo to see : https://unsplash.com/photos/eyoKIj3WTY4

Answer (score 2):

There's direct sunlight only in mountains and hilltop in the left. The flamingo cannot make any sharp shadow. If a shadow is wanted to glue the flamingo tighter to the environment you can try something like this:

[image]

The sunset light is extended down to the flamingo and the tepee. It's kept simple by not letting it reach the foreground sand and rocks.

There'a a masked adjustment layer which exaggerates the yellowish color. The mask has this non-black portion:

[image]

It's painted partially by hand and partially it's made of selections.

The flamingo statue is rotated a little to make the shadow possible and it's colored so that the sunset can have some effect. The flamingo also has some thickness to make clear that its rotated.

The elevation of the horizon is assumed to be just a little below the brightened area of the straight leg. That's why the flamingo body is watched a little upwards. The horizon cannot be at higher because the roofs of the distant houses are not well enough visible, they cannot be very much lower in the valley than the camera.

Another possibility: Keep the flamingo flat as your texts are. If it somehow symbolizes your business it doesn't need to be connected to the terrain.

Answer (score 1):

Just my opinion based upon overall shadows....

[image]

The *key* for me is the bluff behind the teepee. The lighting there clearly show a hard direction for the source (sun). In fact, the sun *may be* behind another peak or bluff due to the harsh shadow behind the teepee at the bottom of that bluff.

Then all the soft, ambient, lighting is due to the sun's refraction off of the atmosphere. That sort of "fills in" areas to create the soft lightning.